# Adding new jar in Netbeans project after building the project

Tags: netbeans, build, jar, project

I am developing a application in Netbeans7.1. I am facing one problem to add new jar file from the app after building the app.

As i know, when we build the project in Netbeans that will create a "jar" file and "lib" directory (which has all the libraries those are being used in the application) into the "dist" directory.

The problem is, I have to add new jar from my application into `/lib/` directory after building the project. So that jar will be used in the application.
How should i do this?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do. Why the jar has to be added after bulding?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a successful build then it means the `jar` you wants to add is required at runtime not at compile time otherwise it wouldn't have compiled.
And if above is the case adding jar is straightforward.

1. Add the `jar` file to **lib** folder.
2. Now open you applications `jar` with some `rar` software like winrar.
3. Goto the `META-INF` folder open the **MANIFEST.MF** file and append the class path with `lib/new_jar_file.jar`.
4. Bingo..You are done.

Here is a screenshot of **MAINIFEST.MF** file and red box shows where to add the above mentioned lines.

[image]